# Launch Fragment (instead of Activity) from Android 7.1 App Shortcut

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-manifest, android-7.1-nougat, app-shortcut

I have decided to look at adding static shortcuts into an application, using this page as reference:

https://developer.android.com/preview/shortcuts.html

The XML for my shortcuts currently looks like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shortcuts xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <shortcut
        android:shortcutId="id"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:shortcutShortLabel="@string/short_label"
        android:shortcutLongLabel="@string/long_label"
        android:shortcutDisabledMessage="@string/disabled_message">
        <intent
            android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
            android:targetPackage="com.example"
            android:targetClass="com.example.Activity" />
        <categories android:name="android.shortcut.category" />
    </shortcut>
</shortcuts>
```

The issue comes from the `targetClass` variable as I cannot find a way to launch a `Fragment` rather than an `Activity`. Most of the main pages I would want to launch from the shortcuts are `Fragments` displayed within an `Activity`. How can I get the `intent` to launch straight to a `Fragment` instead?

Comment: What do you mean by launch straight to a `Fragment`? `Fragment` has to be attached to an `Activity`?

Comment: @TinTran I know that but I want to launch that `Fragment` from that `Activity`. Currently I can't even find a way to launch a `Fragment` child.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can do the following:

1) In the intent specified in `shortcuts.xml`, set a custom intent action string:

```
 <intent
        android:action="com.your.packagename.custom.name"
        android:targetPackage="com.example"
        android:targetClass="com.example.Activity" />
```

2) Check for the `getIntent().getAction()` for intent action in the Activity specified in `android:targetClass`:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    if (CUSTOM_NAME.equals(getIntent().getAction())) {
        // do Fragment transactions here 
    }
}
```

Comment: CUSTOM_NAME? What this constant contains?

Comment: It is `com.your.packagename.custom.name` in this example.

Comment: one more question, i have wrong 2nd type of my fragment, when i tried do Fragment transactions. 
`getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new LanguagesSelectorFragment()).commit();`. Requred  'android.app.Fragment'

Comment: You can replace `getFragmentManager()` with `getSupportFragmentManager()`.

Comment: I used   <intent
            android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
            android:targetPackage="com.soap.mart"
            android:targetClass="com.soap.mart.MainSliderActivity" >
            <extra
                android:name="screen"
                android:value="true" />
        </intent>  in my target java class i used  //Log.e(" ***----** ",getIntent().getExtras().getString("screen"));  to receive value but nothing happens

Comment: What do you mean by nothing happens? Do the extras contains the `screen` key?

Comment: Is there a way to retrive android:shortcutId from intent ?

Comment: I think you can add an extra string to the intent but it is static (not dynamic)

Answer (score 4):

You can easily achieve this with the [Shortbread](https://github.com/MatthiasRobbers/shortbread) library.

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
        
    @Shortcut(id = "movies", shortLabel = "Movies", icon = R.drawable.ic_shortcut_movies)
    fun showMovies() {
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fragment_container, MoviesFragment())
            .commit()
    }
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend it, it hasn't been updated for 2+ years.

Comment: Version 1.1.0 was released a few days ago.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do the redirection on navigation component with DeepLink navigation, The shortcut xml intent will look like below:

```
<intent
        android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
        android:data="<Your deeplink URI, like appname://feature-to-be-names>"
        android:targetClass="activity class with package name"
        android:targetPackage="application id"/>
```

And the onCreate() -> in activity to handle the deeplink navigation

```
intent.dataString?.let {
        navHostFragment.findNavController().navigate(Uri.parse(it), false)
    }
```

This will take care of the multiple shortcut and redirection.